# Image in ImageView showing up smaller than expected (Android)

Tags: android, image, imageview, size, sizing

I have [this animation/code](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) where a tap on the photo enlarges it to the full screen while the rest of the screen turns black. When I use [this banana](http://fitnessandhealthadvisor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bananas1.jpeg) stock photo the size turns out large enough. [image]However, when I pull images from the web using an API the images turn out very small [image] I tried checking the size of the image and it does not seem to be naturally that small. The [water bottle image](http://media.shopwell.com/gladson/00075140005024_full.jpg) is actually h:89 and w:273 pixels when downloaded from the source.

```
//pulling the image and finding its sizes
Glide.with(getContext()).load(currentFood.getImageUrl()).into(ivFullScreen);
    int ih=ivFullImage.getMeasuredHeight();//height of imageView = 1440
    int iw=ivFullImage.getMeasuredWidth();//width of imageView = 2464
    int iH=ivFullImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();//original height of underlying image = 3332
    int iW=ivFullImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();//original width of underlying image = 4442
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "view height: " + ih + " view width: " + iw + " image height: " + iH + " image width: " + iW, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
The Toast showed that the `ivFullImage` size is h:1440 and w:2464 and the image's size is h:3332 and w:4442.
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llFullScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:alpha="0.0"> 
</LinearLayout> 
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ivFullImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bananas1"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

Comment: What is the resolution of that phone/emulator? if it's 1920x1080 or similar the image seems to be in the right size...

Comment: Actually i tried your `ImageView` with bottle and working perfect. Can you try to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`

Comment: @Salem I'm running a Samsung Galaxy S7 (1440 x 2560 pixels )

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I ended up with the water bottle taking up the whole screen http://i982.photobucket.com/albums/ae302/red87445/imagejpeg_0_zpsosg6skyz.jpg   I was wondering if there was a way to enlarge the image less drastically?

Comment: @stumped can you try to delete  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz thansk that helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` attribute to your `ImageView` :

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ivFullImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bananas1"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

More info : [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Comment: It still looks the same and small

Comment: Worked with taking out scaleType and changing the finalBounds offset's y-value

Comment: @stumped my friend im glad to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator/device size is too big it might be natural for the image to look small. Even though, I can see that you're adding the image statically from the XML with `android:src="@drawable/bananas1"`, and not dynamically from the code. If you want to download an image from the internet and add it what you can do is call your ImageView of your layout from your code and then get the image you want to add from the URL you have

```
ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivFullImage);
//get the image from the url using the library you have, convert to bitmap
mImage.setImageBitmap(yourImageInBitmap);
```

Also, in your XML, you need to define the width and height of your ImageView to adjust to the dimensions of the image you're going to insert by saying

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```